# How to stop service immediately and forever

Tags: android

Can somebody please **explain** me why does my service doesn't stop? And how to stop my service immediately when device is locked and stop it forever.
My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

My Receiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(action)) {
            Log.i("isScreen ","on");
        } else
        if(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equals(action)) {
            Log.i("isScreen ","off");
            context.stopService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

My Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("Service ","starts");
    }
}
```

Comment: check your condition in receiver when you unlock device

Comment: @ajay-pandya You mean something like "if device was unlocked then start/stop service"?

Comment: Yes exactly as well check when screen turns off check your context too.

Comment: @ajay-pandya But I just need that service will be stopped when device will be locked

Comment: @ms-yvette But I do stop it when action=action_screen_off.

Answer (score 0):

do you already try this one ?

```
boolean isBound = false;
...
isBound = getApplicationContext().bindService( new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceUI.class), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE );
...
if (isBound)
    getApplicationContext().unbindService(serviceConnection);
```

Comment: My service is not bound. So,thanks for your solution but it won't work.

Comment: how about : 

`public void onDestroy(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }`

in 
`public class MyService extends Service {
........`